# Percorrer Array e exibir em tabela

Tags: php, html5

Necessito adicionar os dados do `array` em uma tabela *HTML*, lembrando que deve ser 3 arrays e apenas HTML e PHP por questões de exigência do professor. está anexado uma montagem de como deve ficar.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
segue meu código:

```
<?php
   $vetor1 = array("GT 1030 DDR4", "GT 1030 GDDR5", "GTX 750", "GTX 750 TI", "GTX 1050 TI", "GTX 1050"); 
   $vetor2 = array(400, 350, 600, 500, 1000, 800); 
   $vetor2 = array("péssima", "regular", "boa", "muito boa", "ótima", "aceitável"); 
   echo "<table>";
?>

<table>
   <tr>
      <th>GPU</th>
      <th>preço</th>
      <th>qualidade</th>
   </tr>
```

Comment: Sua pergunta esta muito vaga, aconselho melhora-lá com exemplos do que espera como resultado, baseado em dados fornecidos.

Answer (score 1):

Subentendo que você queira que os 3 vetores sejam mostrados como 3 linhas abaixo do código HTML que você passou, isso deve servir:

```
<?php
  $vetor1 = array("GT 1030 GDDR5", "GT 1030 DDR4", "GTX 750 TI", "GTX 750", "GTX 1050 TI", "GTX 1050"); 
  $vetor2 = array(400, 350, 600, 500, 1000, 800); 
  $vetor2 = array("péssima", "regular", "boa", "muito boa", "ótima", "aceitável");

  $rows = {$vetor1, $vetor2, $vetor3};
?>

<table>
  <tr>
     <th>GPU</th>
     <th>preço</th>
     <th>qualidade</th>
  </tr>
  <?php
     for($i = 0; $i < count($rows); $i++){
         echo "<tr>";
         for($j = 0; $j < count($rows[i]); $j++){
             echo "<th>".$rows[i][j]."</th>"
         }
         echo "</tr>";
     }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de escrever três arrays, eu recomendaria você representar esse conteúdo em uma estrutura de objeto para o próprio javascript... assim você poderia depois alterar o seu script para entregar esse conteúdo de forma assíncrona ou até mesmo adicionar outras funcionalidades como filtros e ordenação. Dessa forma a manipulação do conteúdo no browser vai ficar muito mais prática.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
let conteudo = [
{ "gpu" : "GT 1030 GDDR5", "preco": 400, qualidade: "péssima" },
{ "gpu" : "GT 1030 DDR4", "preco": 350, qualidade: "regular" },
{ "gpu" : "GTX 750 TI", "preco": 600, qualidade: "boa" },
{ "gpu" : "GTX 750", "preco": 500, qualidade: "muito boa" },
{ "gpu" : "GTX 1050 TI", "preco": 1000, qualidade: "ótima" },
{ "gpu" : "GTX 1050", "preco": 800, qualidade: "aceitavel" }
];

$(document).ready(()=>{
  
  $.each(conteudo, function( index, value ) {
    let linha = 
      `<tr>
        <td>${value.gpu}</td>
        <td>${value.preco}</td>
        <td>${value.qualidade}</td>
       </tr>`
    $('#tbConteudo tbody').append(linha);
  });
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbConteudo" width="100%">
 <thead align="left"> 
    <tr>
      <th>GPU</th>
      <th>preço</th>
      <th>qualidade</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: olá. vlw pela resposta, eu testei e realmente funcionou mas infelizmente eu só posso trabalhar com PHP e HTML para a montagem da tabela e precisa de 3 vetores mesmo, por exigência do professor.